# jasmine: How can i declare a loop of 'its' instead of a loop of 'expects' for testing an angular factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

This is the angular factory i want to test:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('factoryTest',function(){
    return [
        {number: 1, name: 'one'},
        {number: 2, name: 'two'},
        {number: 3, name: 'three'}
    ];
});
```

And this is the jasmine way of testing it:

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_factoryTest_) {
    factoryTest = _factoryTest_;
}));

it('verifies every item has a number', function(){
    for(var i=0;i < factoryTest.length; i++){
        expect(factoryTest[i].number).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
    }
});
```

the above test works however in case of failure you don't know which item is the failing one.

To make the error meaningful it'd have to be refactored into a loop of 'its':

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_factoryTest_) {
    factoryTest = _factoryTest_;
}));

for(var i=0;i < factoryTest.length; i++){
    it('verifies ' + factoryTest[i].name + ' has a number', function(){
        expect(factoryTest[i].number).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
    });
}
```

However, this fails because the factoryTest isn't injected in the describe context. How can i inject the angular factory to make it work?

I've done a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rodhom/woq9fhg9/

I first found the idea of looping 'its', here: http://tosbourn.com/using-loops-in-jasmine/

Comment: What is it you're trying to test? I assume your `factoryTest` function is a mock of a factory.
The tests provided are testing the mock which doesn't provide any value to the end product.
If the requirement being tested is that a factory object always has a number attribute which is an instance of `Number`, then mock the data provider for the factory to test how the actual factory responds to data which is inside and outside of the expected bounds.
Ensure that how out of bounds data is handled is documented and falls within the requirements.

Comment: `factoryTest` is an actual factory (bad naming) that i'm simplified for the question, it's not a mock. Can you explain further `mock the data provider for the factory to test how the actual factory responds to data which is inside and outside of the expected bounds`?

Comment: For example, if your factory is using $http to fetch the data it is providing than use the methods [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) to mock the http backend and return data for the factory to be tested with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*See my earlier comment as I believe you are having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).*

jasmine evaluates the test definitions in stages. At the point in which `describe` is evaluated, the `beforeEach` assigning the `factoryTest` has not been evaluated. *I can't find a reference as to what the exact order is at the moment.*

To have the error message indicate in which object the expectation failed, create a custom matcher and iterate the expectations in the `it` stage.

Define a custom matcher like below:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    var customMatchers = {
        toHaveNumericProperty: function (property) {
            var instance = this.actual;
            var description = instance.name || instance.toString();
            var isNumeric = typeof instance[property] === 'number';

            this.message = function() {
                return isNumeric ? '' : 'Expected \'' + description + '.' + property + '\' to be numeric';
            };

            return isNumeric;
        }
    };

    this.addMatchers(customMatchers);
});
```

Then use it in your tests like this:

```
it('verifies each object has a number',
function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < factoryTest.length; i++) {
        expect(factoryTest[i]).toHaveNumericProperty('number');
    }
})
```

I've [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxf5n2s3/2/) to use this solution

<strike>The solution to your question as asked would to make a closure to contain the `factoryTest` variable.</strike>

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_factoryTest_) {
    factoryTest = _factoryTest_;
}));

for(var i=0;i < factoryTest.length; i++){
    it('verifies ' + factoryTest[i].name + ' has a number', 
        createFactoryTestClosure(factoryTest[i]));
}

function createFactoryTestClosure(factoryElement) {
    return function() {
        expect(factoryElement.number.toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
    };
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about the XY problem but i've definitely fell into it. I've created another fiddle with your answer but it doesn't seem to work. it throws the same error of not been able to read `factoryTest` : you can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rodhom/74r0vcmq/

Comment: psaxton, custom_macher is the solution! The XY problem didn't allow me to see other solutions. Thanks a lot!! :)